# Class::__del__: Attempting to use member object in destructor to free resources fails

Tags: python, google-api-python-client

I have a simple class `Test` below which starts a Google Compute Engine VM and then stops it by either calling a function (**explicit**), or relying on object destruction, via `__del__` (**implicit**).

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = 'secret.json'
        self._compute = googleapiclient.discovery.build('compute',
                                                        'v1',
                                                        cache_discovery=False)
        print('starting vm')
        req = self._compute.instances().start(project='test-project',
                                              zone='us-east1-b',
                                              instance='test-vm',
                                              requestId=uuid.uuid1())
        self.execute(req)
        self._running = True

    def stop(self):
        print('stopping vm')
        req = self._compute.instances().stop(project='test-project',
                                             zone='us-east1-b',
                                             instance='test-vm',
                                             requestId=uuid.uuid1())
        self.execute(req)
        self._running = False

    def execute(self, req):
        print(f'method({req.methodId})')
        resp = req.execute()
        while resp['status'] != 'DONE':
            time.sleep(1)
            resp = req.execute()
        return resp

    def __del__(self):
        if self._running:
            print('stopping in destructor')
            self.stop()
```

The `Test` class is interacted with as follows:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('start test')
    t = Test()

    print('vm running, wait 5 seconds')
    time.sleep(5)

    if len(sys.argv) == 2 and sys.argv[1] == 'stop':
        t.stop()

    print('test done')
```

When using the **explicit** method (ie: calling `t.stop()` **before** the object starts being destructed), the VM stops fine:

```
$ ./test.py stop
start test
starting vm
method(compute.instances.start)
vm running, wait 5 seconds
stopping vm
method(compute.instances.stop)
test done
```

However, when using the **implicit** method (ie: relying on `t` going out of scope, and having `Test::__del__` called), I get an exception thrown from within the `googleapiclient` stack:

```
$ ./test.py 
start test
starting vm
method(compute.instances.start)
vm running, wait 5 seconds
test done
stopping in destructor
stopping vm
method(compute.instances.stop)
Exception ignored in: <bound method Test.__del__ of <__main__.Test object at 0x7fe091720320>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test.py", line 46, in __del__
  File "./test.py", line 32, in stop
  File "./test.py", line 37, in execute
  File "/src/test/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
  File "/src/test/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 846, in execute
  File "/src/test/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 183, in _retry_request
  File "/src/test/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 164, in _retry_request
  File "/src/test/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 198, in request
  File "/src/test/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1926, in request
  File "/src/test/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1595, in _request
  File "/src/test/.venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1502, in _conn_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 975, in sendall
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 944, in send
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 642, in write
ssl.SSLError: Underlying socket connection gone (_ssl.c:2067)
```

**Questions:**

- Is my use of `Test::__del__` to stop my VM illegal?
- By the time `Test::__del__` is called, is it no longer safe to access `self._compute`?
- Is this a bug in the Google API client?
- Is there any way to rely on the destruction of my object to trigger stopping my VM?

Comment: How are you calling your delete method?

Comment: @EsdrasXavier what do you mean? In the one instance I explicitly call `t.stop` (if `"stop"` is passed on the command line), and in the other instance I rely on `Test::__del__` being called automatically at object destruction. It is this latter instance which fails

Comment: I mean, your `Test::__dell__` will not work you call it this way, for the `__del__` method work you must start the instance, use replace your `t.stop()` for `del t` should work fine. If you did that and  I miss understand my bad about it

Comment: @SteveLorimer: The `__del__` method would get called just before the object gets destroyed. I wonder if (for reasons best known to the garbage collector) that is happening late -- by which time the socket is perhaps getting automatically closed? To test this hypothesis, can you print the time instant at which the `__del_` method is entered, and also print the time instant at which you start executing your python file? Perhaps there's too much difference between the two time instants, and the socket is getting closed on its own by timeout, in that interval?

Comment: @fountainhead I'm leaning towards this being a bug in the google api. Since my `Test` object stores `self._compute` it has a reference count to it, and therefore no matter when `Test::__del__` gets called, `self._compute` should be alive and able to be used. I've found this bug only appears when the object goes out of scope at module scope exit. If I wrap this into a function call so it goes out of scope at function exit, the bug disappears.

Comment: @EsdrasXavier the whole point is I don't want to call `t.stop()` or `del t`, I want to rely on the *implicit* calling of the destructor when the object goes out of scope

Comment: @SteveLorimer I see... My bad I miss understand, did you try use `delete()` instead of `stop()`? Have a look at this [link on GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/3f5ad26ad2c1e3c8deceb5844adfb40cf7c2e53f/compute/api/create_instance.py#L119), may help you